# Is it possible to allow Azure elastic jobs access to Azure SQL Databases without the need to allow all Azure resources to the server?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

We are trying to use Azure elastic jobs to run database jobs on a set of Azure SQL databases. The access to these Azure SQL databases is restricted to only certain ip-addresses which we have configured in the firewall rules. When testing the execution of the elastic jobs the elastic job agent cannot access our databases. We do not want to enable access for all Azure Services.
I found a post that it is possible to limit the access by manually adding the ip addresses of the Azure resources of the location we use. (https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/35138) But this means it is still possible for all Azure resources in that location to try and access our servers.

Is there a way to only provide access to our SQL databases for our Elastic Job SQL Agent resource?

Comment: I agree that having to allow ALL azure resources to access the database is a bit much to be able to just allow elastic jobs to access the database

Comment: Hi @Robert Wielink. If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Very thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is no need to allow all Azure resources to the server, but after that we need to list ip whitelist. (https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/35138) as the post also said: `Please go ahead to white list the IP Ranges for the specific data center you are deployed to instead of allowing all IPs from all Azure services.`

I also created a test to prove it.
I turned off this setting of my Azure SQL database.
[image]

Then I executed `EXEC jobs.sp_start_job 'CreateTableTest'` to start a job, I only got an error as follows:
[image]

So I need to add the client ip to the firewall rules of my Azure SQL database. After that, it works well.
[image]

When we allow Azure services and resources to access this server, it will automatically and implicitly add all the ip range of azure services and resources.

**Update:**
I've removed other IP list and the elastic jobs can still run successfully.
[image]
That's amazing!
[image]

Comment: A few remarks: I don't think a data center uses a single outgoing ip. So adding them the way you describe is a bit trial/error to see what ip's are being used. Secondly, doesn't this result in the same issue, but in a smaller scale? I mean: other resources deployed to the same data center (so also resources from other subscriptions) would be able to access the sql server, because they use the same Ip

Comment: Yes, data center outgoing ip is dynamic allocated, we need to add a range of the IP address. Secondly, the ip address is managed by MS. As you said, the issue may be a question of probability and in a smaller scale. I think, `add ip rang` is much less probable than `allow all Azure resources`.

Comment: There is a list of the ip's used by the data center: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519
However, I'm not sure how static this list is. If the list changes the elastic jobs might break until you add the new ip(ranges) to your whitelist.
But as stated before, this only decreases the size of your security hole from all services on Azure to only the Azure services of your datacenter. The original concern still stands. Other Azure tenants can still try to get access to your database via Azure services.

Comment: I think what you said makes sense.For us users, what we can do is to reduce the range of IP addresses to improve security. MS also provided [Advanced Threat Protection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/threat-detection-overview) 
which enables customers to detect and respond to potential threats. If you are not at ease, you can submit an issue to MS.

Comment: Turning this on allows network access to everyone in Azure, without a valid login/password, no one is getting in.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have come up with doing this without either whitelisting huge amounts of ip addresses or allowing all azure services, is to have an automation job that makes a query via the external source, and then if the link fails extract the ip address from the error message and add that to the sql firewall.

This is far from ideal, but at least is more maintainable, and probably more secure.